# 4 switches control 1 led, if a switch change in value led change in value

Tags: verilog

```
A room has 4 doors with a light switch next to each door, totaling 4 light 
switches. Inside the room there is only one light in the center of the 
ceiling. Design a circuit that allows all 4 switches to control that single
center light. Each switch needs to be able to turn the light on if it is off, 
and off if it is currently on.
```

I was able to write the code but my TA said I can't think like in term of computer science, and told me to rewrite the code in term of hardware

I made several attempts and still can't figure it out, please help
This is my latest attempt

```
assign led = (sw[0] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[3])|
             (~sw[0] & sw[1] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[3])|
             (~sw[0] & ~sw[1] & sw[2] & ~sw[3])|
             (~sw[0] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[2] & sw[3])|
```

Comment: Think about the wiring to make this work and the flow of electricity to the light bulb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A B C D  | Light
---------|-------
0 0 0 0  |   0      _ _ _ 
0 0 0 1  |   1   => A.B.C.D
0 0 1 1  |   0      _ _   _
0 0 1 0  |   1   => A.B.C.D
0 1 1 0  |   0      _
0 1 1 1  |   1   => A.B.C.D
0 1 0 1  |   0      _   _ _
0 1 0 0  |   1   => A.B.C.D
1 1 0 0  |   0          _
1 1 0 1  |   1   => A.B.C.D
1 1 1 1  |   0            _  
1 1 1 0  |   1   => A.B.C.D
1 0 1 0  |   0        _
1 0 1 1  |   1   => A.B.C.D
1 0 0 1  |   0        _ _ _
1 0 0 0  |   1   => A.B.C.D
```

A, B, C and D are the switches. The truth table is encoded in gray code to have between each lines only one input changed. The initial state is "all switches are off, the light is off". The equation of the light is the logical OR of all states when light is 1. There are 8 states : when only one switch is ON and when only one switch is OFF.

For now, you have coded only half of them, when only one switch is ON. For all 8 states, the equation becomes :

```
assign led = ( sw[0] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[3])|
             (~sw[0] &  sw[1] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[3])|
             (~sw[0] & ~sw[1] &  sw[2] & ~sw[3])|
             (~sw[0] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[2] &  sw[3])|
             (~sw[0] &  sw[1] &  sw[2] &  sw[3])|
             ( sw[0] & ~sw[1] &  sw[2] &  sw[3])|
             ( sw[0] &  sw[1] & ~sw[2] &  sw[3])|
             ( sw[0] &  sw[1] &  sw[2] & ~sw[3]);
```